# Remove Twitter mentions from Pandas column

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I have a dataset that includes Tweets from Twitter. Some of them also have user mentions such as `@thisisauser`. I try to remove that text at the same time I do other cleaning processes.

```
def clean_text(row, options):

    if options['lowercase']:
        row = row.lower()

    if options['decode_html']:
        txt = BeautifulSoup(row, 'lxml')
        row = txt.get_text()

    if options['remove_url']:
        row = row.replace('http\S+|www.\S+', '')

    if options['remove_mentions']:
        row = row.replace('@[A-Za-z0-9]+', '')

    return row

clean_config = {
    'remove_url': True,
    'remove_mentions': True,
    'decode_utf8': True,
    'lowercase': True
    }

df['tweet'] = df['tweet'].apply(clean_text, args=(clean_config,))
```

However, when I run the above code, all the Twitter mentions are still on the text. I verified with a Regex online tool that my Regex is working correctly, so the problem should be on the Pandas's code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are misusing `replace` method on a string because it does not accept regular expressions, only fixed strings (see docs at https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace for more).

The right way of achieving your needs is using `re` module like:

```
import re
re.sub("@[A-Za-z0-9]+","", "@thisisauser text")
' text'
```

Comment: Damn. I had first the `str.replace` from Pandas and then I changed it to `replace` from Python. But I forgot to change to `re.sub` as well. Thank you a lot

Comment: This does not count for screen names that have underscore (e.g. "@my_user"). It has to change to "@[A-Za-z0-9_]+"

Answer (score 1):

the problem is with the way you used replace method & not pandas

see output from the REPL

```
>>> my_str ="@thisisause"
>>> my_str.replace('@[A-Za-z0-9]+', '')
'@thisisause'
```

replace doesn't support regex. Instead do use regular expressions [library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) in python as mentioned in the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54734032/1552998)

```
>>> import re
>>> my_str
'hello @username hi'
>>> re.sub("@[A-Za-z0-9]+","",my_str)
'hello  hi'
```

Comment: I tested it here and it is working. http://regexr.com/48he7 I guess it is different in Python?

Answer (score 1):

Removing Twitter mentions, or words that start with a `@` char, in Pandas, you can use

```py
df['tweet'] = df['tweet'].str.replace(r'\s*@\w+', '', regex=True)
df['tweet'] = df['tweet'].str.replace(r'\s*\B@\w+', '', regex=True)
df['tweet'] = df['tweet'].str.replace(r'\s*@\S+', '', regex=True)
df['tweet'] = df['tweet'].str.replace(r'\s*@\S+\b', '', regex=True)
```

If you need to remove remaining leading/trailing spaces after the replacement, add `.str.strip()` after `.str.replace` call.

*Details*:

- `\s*@\w+` - zero or more whitespaces, `@` and one or more "word" chars (letters, digits, underscores (and other connector punctuation in Python 3.x), also some diacritics (in Python 3.x) (see [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/6uueEY/1))
- `\s*\B@\w+` - zero or more whitespaces, a position other than word boundary, `@` and one or more "word" chars (see [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/6uueEY/2))
- `\s*@\S+` - zero or more whitespaces, `@` and one or more non-whitespace chars (see [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/6uueEY/3))
- `\s*@\S+\b` - zero or more whitespaces, `@` and one or more non-whitespace chars (as many as possible) followed with a word boundary (see [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/6uueEY/4)).

Without Pandas, use one of the the above regexps in `re.sub`:

```py
text = re.sub(r'...pattern here...', '', text)
## or
text = re.sub(r'...pattern here...', '', text).strip()
```